# T-SQL Convert Hex to decimal

Tags: t-sql

I try to use TSQL and I get some problem to convert hex to decimal when the value is inside a variable.

My code is:

```
SET @hex = SUBSTRING(@x,1,2) --give 1e
SET @hex = '0x' + @hex
SELECT CAST (@hex AS int)
```

I get the error that the conversion failed when converting the varchar value to int

I don't know what it's wrong and so far I can't find solution

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works (for SQL Server 2008 or later):

```
declare @hex varchar(316)
SET @hex = '1e' --SUBSTRING(@x,1,2) --give 1e
SET @hex = '0x' + @hex
SELECT CONVERT(int,CONVERT (binary(1),@hex,1))
```

See "Binary Styles" on the [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.100).aspx) page.

Comment: I ran your query, it gives result as 48. But decimal of hex 1e is 30. any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @th1rdey3 - When I run it on my machine, the result it gives is 30. When I run it against a 2005 server it gives 48. That's why I said it was for 2008 or later. For 2005 it acts as described for style `0` - it's telling you that the ASCII value for `0` is 48.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Interesting difference, can you explain what exactly is the difference between `CONVERT` before and after `SQL Server 2008`? Could not find that in the link of your answer.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste - the difference is that they started using the `style` parameter for converting to/from binary values. The existing conversion behaviour was then documented as style `0` and styles `1` and `2` were added, specifically for hex conversion.

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to varbinary.

Comment: for more than one byte you must increase `binary(1)` or `varbinary(n)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think T-SQL can explicitly convert a string of hex to a number, but it CAN convert a hex number so you can kind of trick it into doing what you want. Like this:

```
DECLARE @hex nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @select nvarchar(200)
DECLARE @parm nvarchar(200)
DECLARE @retVal int
SET @hex = '0x1e'
SET @select = 'SELECT @retVal = CAST(' + @hex + ' AS int)'
SET @parm = '@retVal int OUTPUT'
EXEC sp_executesql @select, @parm, @retVal OUTPUT
SELECT @retVal
```

You'll want to validate @hex to protect from SQL injection attacks, and you'll probably want to put this in a function or stored proc

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FN_HEXTOINT(@HEX varchar(MAX) = NULL)
RETURNS @RETORNO TABLE(INTHEX INT)
AS 
BEGIN
  
  SET @HEX = UPPER(@HEX)
  
  DECLARE @TABHEX VARCHAR(16) = '0123456789ABCDEF'
  DECLARE @CHARX VARCHAR(1)
  DECLARE @POSCHARX INT 
  DECLARE @BASE INT = 16
  DECLARE @I INT = LEN(@HEX)
  DECLARE @LENSTR INT = LEN(@HEX)
  DECLARE @EXPOENTE INT = 36
  DECLARE @N10 FLOAT = 0.01

  
    WHILE (@I> 0)
    BEGIN
    
     SET @CHARX = SUBSTRING (@HEX, @i,1)
     SET @POSCHARX  = PATINDEX('%'+@CHARX+'%',  @TABHEX);  
     IF @POSCHARX > 0 
     BEGIN
       SET @N10 = @N10 + ((@POSCHARX - 1) * POWER(@BASE, (@LENSTR-@I)))  
     END
       
    SET @I = @I - 1
    
    END
    
      INSERT INTO @RETORNO 
    SELECT (ROUND(@N10 + 0.001,1)) AS RET
  
RETURN 
END
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?